# Producer/consumer threads not working using pthread for DNS lookup

Tags: c, pthreads, dns, consumer, producer

I am using the producer/consumer problem to make a multi-threaded DNS resolver.  I solved it without multi-threading, so I am quite certain that that part of my code works.  Basically, I'm creating one producer to write, and (will be creating) many consumers to read.  At the current time, I'm reading in from a file with IP addresses in it.  I can't figure out why my producer thread isn't running; I'll need to figure out whats going on with this before I can get my consumers running.  Any help will be much appreciated.

here is my code (thus far):

```
/*
 * dns_lookup.c
 */


#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "linkedlist.h"

const int BUFF_SIZE = 20;

int ip_count;

FILE *fp;

list_t *list;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;


void *do_work(char *addr)
{
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *result;
char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST];


int rc = 0;
int count = 0;

// initialize the addrinfo struct
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
hints.ai_protocol = 0;
hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
hints.ai_addr = NULL;
hints.ai_next = NULL;

// convert the dotted-quad address to an ip address
rc = getaddrinfo(addr, NULL,&hints, &result);
if (rc != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"getaddrinfo failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(rc));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("%s -> ", addr);

rc = getnameinfo(result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen, hbuf, sizeof(hbuf), NULL, 0, NI_NAMEREQD);
if (count++ > 0) printf(",");
if (rc != 0) {
    printf("%s", addr);
}
else {
    printf("%s",hbuf);
}

result = result->ai_next;

printf("\n");
}

void *producer(void *param);
void *consumer(void *param);
void *init();

int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
fp=fopen("access.log", "r");

list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
list->head = NULL;

pthread_t producer_tid;
pthread_t consumer_tid;

pthread_attr_t attr;

pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
pthread_attr_init(&attr);

pthread_create(&producer_tid, &attr, producer, NULL);
}




void *producer(void *param)
{
printf("%s", "thread created");
char line[1024];

while (!feof(fp))
{
    fgets(line, sizeof line, fp);
    char *tempstr = strtok(line, " ");
    char *ipaddr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
    strncpy(ipaddr, tempstr, 20);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    add(list, ipaddr);
    node_t *temp = get(list, 0);
    printf("%s\n", temp->data);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
}

void *consumer(void *param)
{
char *addr;
addr = get(list, 0);
do_work(addr);
}
```

EDIT:
I fixed up some of my code, and I think that it SHOULD work. However, it still doesn't.

```
/*
 * dns_lookup.c
 */


#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "linkedlist.h"

const int BUFF_SIZE = 20;

int ip_count;

FILE *fp;

list_t *list;

sem_t full;
sem_t empty;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;


void *do_work(char *addr)
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result;
    char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST];


    int rc = 0;
    int count = 0;

    // initialize the addrinfo struct
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hints.ai_addr = NULL;
    hints.ai_next = NULL;

    // convert the dotted-quad address to an ip address
    rc = getaddrinfo(addr, NULL,&hints, &result);
    if (rc != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"getaddrinfo failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%s -> ", addr);

    rc = getnameinfo(result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen, hbuf, sizeof(hbuf), NULL, 0, NI_NAMEREQD);
    if (count++ > 0) printf(",");
    if (rc != 0) {
        printf("%s", addr);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s",hbuf);
    }

    result = result->ai_next;

    printf("\n");

    //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *producer(void *param);
void *consumer(void *param);
void *init();

void main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
    fp=fopen("access.log", "r");

    list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    list->head = NULL;

    int thread_count = atoi(argc);


    pthread_t producer_tid;
    pthread_t consumer_tid[thread_count];

    pthread_attr_t attr;

    //ip_count = 0;

    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFF_SIZE);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);


    pthread_create(&producer_tid, NULL, producer, NULL);

    int threads;
    for(threads=0; threads<=thread_count; threads++)
    {
        pthread_create(&consumer_tid[threads], NULL, consumer, NULL);
    }

    pthread_join(producer_tid, NULL);

    for(threads=0; threads<=thread_count; threads++)
    {
        pthread_join(consumer_tid[threads], NULL);
    }

    exit(fp);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *producer(void *param)
{
    printf("thread created%s");
    char line[1024];
    while (1)
    {
        sem_wait(&empty);
        while (!feof(fp))
        {
            fgets(line, sizeof line, fp);
            char *tempstr = strtok(line, " ");
            char *ipaddr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
            strncpy(ipaddr, tempstr, 20);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            add(list, ipaddr);
            node_t *temp = get(list, 0);
            printf("%s\n", temp->data);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        sem_post(&full);
    }
}

void *consumer(void *param)
{
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&full);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        char *addr;
        addr = get(list, 0);
        do_work(addr);
        remove_head(list);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(&empty);
    }

}
```

I don't see anything working.  Any suggestions?

I keep getting segfaults when I debug it. I don't know why or where they are coming from; I'm new to pthreads, so I may have missed something, but to me it looks as if it should work.

Comment: If you debug it in a debugger, then the debugger should stop on the line where the error is. Maybe you could point that line out to us, or at least add a stack-trace (gdb command `bt`) to your question. Also, in the debugger you can examine variables to see if they look okay and there are no `NULL` pointers for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your producer thread is actually running... for a very short amount of time. In your `main()` function you create the producer thread and then immediately afterwards your program terminates (because the `main` function returns. Try adding this before you return:

```
pthread_join(producer_tid, &return_value_p);
```

Once you start creating consumer threads, you will need to make sure you are also waiting for all of them to finish before you exit your program too.

Comment: I don't understand where the & return_value_p is from.  I did try to use
    `pthread_join(producer_tid, NULL);`
but it did nothing.  the &return_value_p is undeclared, so I'm getting an error.

Comment: Well, of course you have to declare it. But according to the manpage it's optional so `NULL` is ok. Also according to the manpage I didn't get the type of the first argument right. Will edit.

Comment: 'you will need to make sure you are also waiting for all of them to finish before you exit your program too' why?

Comment: @MartinJames otherwise they might not have a chance to complete their work before the program exits?